# С#. Vue, axios, есть простое api на asp dotnet. также есть frontend часть. При вызове метода updateClient выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, .net

Ошибка:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:51320/api/Client/updateClient' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Код frontend части:

```js
updateClient(upClient) {
   axios.put('localhost:51320/api/Client/updateClient', {
      id: upClient.clientId,
      name: upClient.lastName,
      middleName: upClient.middleName,
      address: upClient.address,
      passportNumber: upClient.passportNumber,
      phone: upClient.phone
   })
   console.log(upClient.name);
   console.log(upClient.middleName);

},
```

Код с#. Контроллер получающий на вход объект класса ReqUpCient:

```cs
[HttpPut("updateClient")]
public async Task<RespUpClient> updateClient([FromQuery] ReqUpClient client)
{
   return await bankService.updateClient(client);
}

//Также в файле Stsrtup.cs я прописал ниже указанную строку для CORS-запросов, но всё равно 
//не работает
app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

Comment: Возможно стоит указать протокол HTTP в axios.put

Comment: Посмотрите при обращении к целевому адресу, есть ли в ответе заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin, и эта нстройка должна быть на уелевом хосте запроса, а не на исходном.